# Getting Scrapy Loggers

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I'm running Scrapy from a script using the [Core API](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html), using the CrawlerProcess class. According to the docs, Scrapy can configure the logging using [configure_logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging) function when running spiders this way. How would I then get the Scrapy logger (So I am able to add handlers and filters?). It looks like Scrapy uses the root logger when using a config file, is it possible to redirect that to a seperate logger for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get the loggers for that purpose. Just pass the settings dict to `scrapy.utils.log.dictConfig`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig. You can use `scrapy.utils.log.DEFAULT_LOGGING` as a reference:

```
DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'loggers': {
        'scrapy': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'twisted': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    }
}
```

For instance,

```
from scrapy.utils import log

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
})
log.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'loggers': {
        'scrapy': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    }
})
```

Also, if you only want to decrease verbosity, take a look at the [LOG_LEVEL](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-level) Scrapy setting.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, it seems to have some effect. However Scrapy still logs on the Debug level after I set it to error in my own dictConfig. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry for the imprudent answer. You have to call `dictConfig`, but only after the `CrawlerProcess` is initialized. I'll update my answer.